# How to analyze the value of convergence of functions of random matrices?

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, probability-distributions, random-matrices, free-probability

Consider a random i.i.d matrix $\mathbf{A}_{m\times n}$ with entries generated from a complex Gaussian distribution with zero mean and unit variance. I am interested in the large dimension analysis of the expression ($m,n\rightarrow\infty$ with fixed $m/n$):
\begin{align}
\label{eq:lll}
\mathbf{a}^\mathrm{H}\left(\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^\mathrm{H}+\mathbf{I}_m\right)^{-1}\mathbf{a},
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{I}_m$ represents the identity matrix and $\mathbf{a}$ is one of the columns of $\mathbf{A}$.
According to the law of large numbers, we know that $\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^\mathrm{H}\rightarrow\mathbf{I}_m$. I expect the following result to hold:
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^\mathrm{H}+\mathbf{I}_m\right)^{-1}\rightarrow 0.5\mathbf{I}_m.
\end{align}
However, my Matlab simulation does not verify this. I have the following questions:

1- Can we analytically compute the convergence value of $\mathbf{a}^\mathrm{H}\left(\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^\mathrm{H}+\mathbf{I}_m\right)^{-1}\mathbf{a}$?

2- Are there any sources that provide clear explanations about the convergence of functions of i.i.d matrices?

Comment: well since this matrix $M=AA^{H}$ is self-adjoint, you have a eigendecomposition and thus a nice formula for the inverse https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298616/what-is-inverse-of-ia  \begin{equation}
\left( A + I\right)^{-1}
=\left( Q \Lambda Q^{-1} + I\right)^{-1}
=\left( Q \left(\Lambda + I \right) Q^{-1}\right)^{-1}
= Q \left(\Lambda + I \right)^{-1} Q^{-1}
\end{equation}

Comment: i suppose one could also try the Portmanteau theorem, but  that would require proving continuity of the above inverse procedure.

Comment: What does $\frac1n AA^T \to I_m$ mean when $n,m\to+\infty$ (both) with fixed $m/n$?

Comment: I suggest the experiment (from, e.g, matlab) to draw histograms of eigenvalues of $AA^T/n$ and of the matrix $(AA^T/n + I_m)$ of interest. The eigenvalues of $AA^T/n$  would approximately follow the Marcenko-Pastur law, so the two matrices are very far from proportional to identity when m/n is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Assume real entries.  Let $b$ be a column of $A$ and write $\tilde A$ the matrix $A$ with that column removed so that $AA^T = \tilde A\tilde A^T + bb^T$.
By the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula,
$$
b^T(AA^T + n I_m)^{-1}b
= b^T(\tilde A\tilde A^T + nI_m)^{-1}b - \frac{b^T(\tilde A\tilde A^T + nI_m)^{-1}bb^T(\tilde A\tilde A^T + nI_m)^{-1}b}{1 + b^T(\tilde A\tilde A^T/n + I_m)^{-1}b}.
$$
This can be written $Z-Z^2/(1+Z) = Z/(1+Z)$ for
$Z=b^T(\tilde A\tilde A^T + n I_m)^{-1}b$.
Now by independence, since $b$ is normal, by the Hanson-Wright inequality (concentration of quadratic forms), $Z \approx trace[(\tilde A\tilde A^T + n I_m)^{-1}]$. The quantity $trace[(\tilde A\tilde A^T + n I_m)^{-1}]$ can be characterized by the limiting spectral distribution of $\tilde A\tilde A^T/n$ given by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution.

Answer (score -1):

We assume that $A$ is a real matrix. Let $B=[b_{i,j}]=\dfrac{1}{n}AA^T$.

$b_{i,i}=1/n ||U||^2$, where $U=[u_j]$ is the $i^{th}$ row of $A$.

$E(b_{i,i})=1/n\sum_j E({u_j}^2)=1$ and $var(b_{i,i})=\dfrac{1}{n^2}n.var({u_j}^2)=\dfrac{2}{n}$;

In the same way, if $i\not= j$, then $E(b_{i,j})=0$ and $var(b_{i,j})=\dfrac{1}{n}$.

With probability $997/1000$, $|X-E(X)|\leq 3\sigma(X)$ (for a normal law).

Then, "in general", $|b_{i,j}-\delta_{i,j}|\leq \dfrac{3\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{n}}=O(1/\sqrt{n})$.

Finally, when $n$ is great, the $b_{i,j}$'s are close to the $\delta_{i,j}$'s and $a^T(B+I_m)^{-1}a$ is -entrywise- close to $\dfrac{1}{2}||a||^2$.